# How to change ActionSheetDatePicker origin on iPAD

Tags: ios, ipad, datepicker, uiactionsheet

I'm opening ActionSheetDatePicker on a table view cell tap as:

```
[ActionSheetDatePicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select Date"
                       datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate
                       selectedDate:[NSDate date]
                           doneBlock:^(ActionSheetDatePicker *picker, id selectedDate, id origin) {                                                     dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:selectedDate];
                                [self fetchHistoryForDate];
                                }
              cancelBlock:^(ActionSheetDatePicker *picker) {
                           NSLog(@"Block Picker Canceled");}
                                                origin:tableView];
```

But it shows like this on iPAD.
[image]
How can I change it's direction? I'm using [ActionSheetPicker-3.0](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this try to change `origin` argument like this.

```
[ActionSheetDatePicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select Date"
                       datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate
                       selectedDate:[NSDate date]
                           doneBlock:^(ActionSheetDatePicker *picker, id selectedDate, id origin) {                                                     dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:selectedDate];
                                [self fetchHistoryForDate];
                                }
              cancelBlock:^(ActionSheetDatePicker *picker) {
                           NSLog(@"Block Picker Canceled");}
                                                origin:tableView.tableFooterView];
```